# How can I call a variable that contains a consecutive number?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a bunch of consecutive variables like $can001,$can002,$can003. And I need to call each one in a for clause in order to insert its content into a query. But when executing this query, the value stored into my MySQL table is $can001,$can002,$can003, doesn't insert what is into each variable. This is my code:

```
$sq = "";
$query = "INSERT INTO estado (pla,cla,fec";
for($i=1;$i<103;$i++){
    if($i<10){
        $num = '00'.$i;
    }
    elseif($i>=10&&$i<100){
        $num = '0'.$i;
    }
    else{
        $num = $i;
    }
    $query.= ",est".$num.",can".$num;
    $cant = "$"."can".$num;
    $sq.= ",'".$carro[$i]."','$cant'";
}
$query.= ") VALUES ('$pla','$cla','$fec'";
$query.= $sq;       
$query.= ")";
```

I have 102 variables and I am joining it in var $cant, so it could get what is on variable $can001 for example, and then inserting it into the query.

Sorry for my horrible coding and my horrible English. Thanks

Comment: Why are you explicitly declaring 100+ consecutive variables instead of working with an array?

Comment: Please use an array instead of douzens of variables.

Comment: Arrays will helps your program to become scalable so if you have 3 or 1000 variables, there would be no change in your code.

Comment: Also you are looking for http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score 0):

I think you want http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

```
$cant = eval("$"."can".$num);
```

You have a bunch of PHP variables such as $can001 = 4; $can002 =5; etc? If so you will want to EVAL the string name of the variable as I showed above.

Comment: Why would you use `eval` instead of variable variables?

Comment: Because I haven't used PHP in a long time  and I forgot about it is why I personally wouldn't... :)

Comment: Didn't work, I used an array instead. Thanks so much.